# Formik creates infinite renders when initial value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-scripts

I am using formik in react js project. The form has first name input which takes initial values from local storage if available. On change of first name input, I change its value in local storage.

```
const prefilledValues = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem("pre-signup-form"));`

useEffect(() =>
 { window.localStorage.setItem( "pre-signup-form", 
   JSON.stringify({ ...prefilledValues, ...formik.values }) ); 
}, [formik.values, prefilledValues]);
```

I am using `useFormik` to set initial values. When I change the first name input, which basically changes the value in local storage and hence initial values, It causes too many renders and the page becomes unresponsive.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-saha-63bp8t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-hill-85penz?file=/src/App.js) plain react code for react form and try modifying for Formik. Accessing localstorage in incognito will give error which u will have to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to separate logic with localStorage, move it to the custom hook.
Check this approach there https://codesandbox.io/s/local-storage-d5m1zx?file=/src/App.js

I moved logic with LC to useLocalStorage hook. Now changing the name doesn't cause an infinite render.